# Application that uninstalls itself Xamarin.Forms C#

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I wanted to create an application with a button to uninstall it or completely remove it from my mobile. I looked at many topics but nothing works with Xamarin.Forms, I wanted to know if anyone will have a solution thank you :)

```
private void ButtonUninstall_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       
        
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionDelete);
        intent.SetData(Android.Net.Uri.Parse("com.companyname.calpok"));

        Console.WriteLine(intent);
    }
```

we cannot do StartActivities with Xamarin.Forms

Do you have any suggestions? or it is not possible to delete files with xamarin.forms?

Comment: first, please do NOT post code as images.  2nd, if you can do it in native Android you can do it in Xamarin.  3rd, Xamarin Forms is a **cross platform** UI framework, so if you want to do something platform specific, use a DependencyService or custom renderer.

Comment: oh sorry I'm new to stackoverflow, otherwise thank you for your answer I made a DependencyService Thank you!

Comment: please see [ask] for an overview of the site rules